# windows composer.exe error: not run correctly [exit code -1073741819] and no output was returned

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

windows 10 use https://getcomposer.org/download/ to install composer

but install error

[image]

```
The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code -1073741819] and no output was returned.
```

Openssl is enabled

php version 7.0.29

---

then use compser.phar install

use: composer -v

[image]

but Other commands Return nothing，Quit after 3 seconds

```
D:\www\jsc_on_api\trunk>composer remove yly-openapi/yly-openapi-sdk -vvv
Running 2.2.18 (2022-08-20 11:33:38) with PHP 7.0.9 on Windows NT / 10.0
Reading ./composer.json (D:\www\jsc_on_api\trunk\composer.json)
Loading config file ./composer.json (D:\www\jsc_on_api\trunk\composer.json)
Checked CA file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/ssl/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/pki/tls/certs does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/pki/tls/certs does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/ssl/certs does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/ssl does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/share/certs does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/share/certs does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/ssl/certs does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/ssl/certs does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /opt/local/share/curl does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /opt/local/share/curl does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/share/curl does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/share/curl does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/share/ssl/certs does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/share/ssl/certs does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /etc/ssl does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /etc/ssl does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/ssl does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/etc/ssl does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/openssl does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/etc/openssl does not exist or it is not a directory.
Checked CA file /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1 does not exist or it is not a file.
Checked directory /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1 does not exist or it is not a directory.
 
D:\www\jsc_on_api\trunk>
```

I tried different versions，but failed

Comment: _"The exit code -1073741819 in hex is 0xC0000005. If you look up this code in Microsoft's documentation (NTSTATUS Values) you will see that it indicates that your program was terminated due to an access violation. This error can occur for a variety of reasons, including de-referencing a NULL pointer or referencing an invalid address."_ ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379441/error-code-34exited-with-code-107374181934.html#answer-379350)) Please use an installation method for composer that is compatible with _your_ system configuration.

Comment: Where does the PHP version requirement of 7.0.29 stem from in your configuration? Is it an option for you to use the current PHP version or are you running legacy tests against the composer setup and want to learn if you can get it to work with that specific version?

Comment: @hakre tks，when change to php7.3，it work，but why？my colleague's computer can， but I can't。

Comment: wipe your machine, reset it to the factory settings and reinstall the operating system. that should be fastest. if it then still does not work I'd wonder about why. until then just make fresh.

Comment: tks , happy life,

Comment: good luck. and ping me here if the problem persists after resetting the development configuration. happy to help. @陈礼松  (if you develop in a team it can often make sense to have a development VM in the project so that all the tooling can be provisioned in there. a classic is Vagrant for that - then such problems don't need to be solved individually and you just provision the VM with a single configuration)